# Сравнение двух объектов с возвратом изменений

Tags: c#

```
 public class Product
{
    public string ID;
    public string Name;

    public Product(string id, string name)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public class AdvancedProduct : Product
{
    public string CurrentVersion;

    public AdvancedProduct(string id, string name, string version)
        : base(id, name) { }
}

public class PChanges
{
    public bool NameChanged = false;
    public bool VersionChanged = false;

    public PChanges() { }

}

public class ProductComparer
{
    PChanges changes = new PChanges();

    public ProductComparer() { }

    public PChanges Compare(AdvancedProduct p1, AdvancedProduct p2)
    {
        if (p1.Name != p2.Name)
            changes.NameChanged = true;
        if (p1.CurrentVersion != p2.CurrentVersion)
            changes.VersionChanged = true;

        return changes;

    }
}
```

Необходимо иметь возможность сравнения продуктов, причем помимо `AdvancedProduct` наследников у `Product` будет достаточно много. Вопрос

1. Как лучше реализовать иерархическую проверку полей, т.е. сначала проверка полей базового класса Product затем проверку дополнительных полей класса наследника AdvancedProduct итд. Существует ли подходящий шаблон?
2. Как все это сделать, но сделать достаточно гибко для последующего использования

Comment: Отнаследуйте Product от IComparable<Product>, сделайте метод Compare виртуальным и переопределяйте его во всех наследниках, реализуя внутри соответствующую логику.

Comment: Интерфейс IComparable и метод Compare возвращает int, а мне надо чот б возвращал PChanges или его наследников

Comment: А как вы собираетесь сравнивать разные порождённые классы? Например, Product с AdvancedProduct?

Comment: >  мне надо чот б возвращал PChanges или его наследников

Напишите свой интерфейс и наследуйте его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Независимо от того, каким образом будет производиться сравнение, Ваш класс PChanges потребуется модифицировать под каждого наследника Product, либо явно передавать тип и через рефлексию разбираться, а что же там поменялось, а было ли это свойство или поле, ну и т.д.
Я бы посоветовал по новой взвесить необходимость подобного сравнения и вероятнее всего придётся уйти в ту же рефлексию, так как заранее неизвестно что может оказаться в том или ином наследнике, чтобы добавить это в некий класс PChanges.

В первую очередь стоит определиться, а требуется ли подобная гибкость, либо же возможность создавать наследников как таковых будет лишь у Вас, а в таком случае всё решится закрытием тех или иных методов/классов в internal.

Answer (score 1):

Как написал выше Flammable, надо создать виртуальный метод Compare и в нём осуществлять сравнение, но в качестве возвратного значения использовать коллекцию типа string (как это сделано в приложенных постах).

[Compare two objects and find the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951233/compare-two-objects-and-find-the-differences),
[Comparing two objects and returning the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343769/comparing-two-objects-and-returning-the-differences)